# Frame is Null when SelectionChanged (ListBox)?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

I am using a ListBox to act as a "Navigation" Bar. When the user selects an item (eg: Options), ill change the source of the frame. However, I need to have the first item selected in order for it to look like that page is active.

I added this to my ListBoxItem Styles:
`<Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"></Setter>`

The only issue with this is, I get a Null Exception Error:
[image]

How can i "select" the Item in the ListBox after the PageContainer (Frame) is defined? I am very new to WPF, but I still don't understand why the Frame is not defined before the selectedIndex Event is fired.

For clarification `PageNavigation` is the ListBox and `PageContainer` is the frame.

**On a side note**

Should I:

1. Even use a ListBox for something like a multi-page software (ie:
   [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/media/131867/ccleaner1.png))
2. Be using a frame and pages. (Iv'e seen another way to use Custom
   User Controls, but i thought that was a bit odd)

**XAML**

```
<Style x:Key="PageNavigation" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <!--<Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="1"></Setter>-->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#eee"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="0, 0, 1, 0" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="#eee">
                    <ScrollViewer Focusable="false">
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"></StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Inside Main Window:

```
        <ListBox Name="PageNavigation" Style="{StaticResource PageNavigation}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PageNavigationItem}" SelectionChanged="PageNavigation_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBoxItem Tag="Home.xaml">Home</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Tag="TestPage.xaml">Test Page</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Tag="OptionsPage.xaml">Options</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: @Ganesh I added the XAML. Please let me know if there are any issues, or if you need more information.

Comment: Are you placing your ListBox First and then Frame in the XAML?

Comment: @EliteGamer just a friendly ping for bounty ;)

Comment: @NETscape no problem. I forgot about it once it told me i had to wait 6 hours LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just so happened to read the ["Initialized vs. Loaded"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/19/loadedvsinitialized.aspx) article the other day and I think it may apply to this very question.

What I think is happening is the control holding `PageContainer` and `PageNavigation` is beginning initialization.  What you learn from the article is that, all child elements will finish initializing before the parent `Initialized` event is fired.

The article also states:

> The Initialized event typically fires when the properties of an element have all been set.

With that being said, I'm thinking that your `PageNavigation` is being initialized before your `PageContainer` even exists, so when `SelectionChanged` is fired and you try to access the control--you get the NRE.

Also, I've had issues in the past, where `SelectionChanged` would fire during application start-up, during intialization; then once when I specified the `SelectedItem/Index`.  I suspect this could also be a problem in your case.

At the end of the day, a null test would prevent the NRE, and the source would then only get set when the `PageContainer` exists--this is also a common practice.

```
if(this.PageContainer != null)
{
    this.PageContainer.Source = new Uri(navigationPath, UriKind.Relative);
}
```

Comment: Perfect example of why you should include the code as text also, not just a screenshot :) . Even a text snippet with a `//Throws NRE here` would be better than the screenshot. Thanks assigning bounty!